# PHP regex return zero result

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match-all

i have following PHP curl and regex code. i'd like to get post header from website. In actual, there are 10 articles. but code returns zero result.

PHP:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "www.mahsumakbas.net";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

@preg_match_all('/<h2 class="entry-title">(.*)<\/h2>/' ,$content, $matches); 


for ($i=0;  $i< sizeof($matches[1]); $i++)
    echo $matches[1][$i]."<br/>";

?>
```

On www.mahsumakbas.net web page there are 10  `<h2 class="entry-title">` enclosed with `</h2>`

what do i miss?

Comment: what do you think will happen when they add a simple extra space, or an extra attribute, to those h2's ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003

Comment: the tl;dr is: don't use regex to parse html. `$results=[];$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($content);foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("h2") as $h2){if($h2->getAttribute("class") !=="entry-title")continue;$matches[]=$h2->textContent;}var_dump($matches);`

Comment: `for ($i=0;  $i< sizeof($matches[1]); $i++)` is not the way to loop over an array in PHP, use `foreach` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$url = "www.mahsumakbas.net";
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt(... other options you want...)
$html = curl_exec($c);

curl_close($c);
preg_match_all("'<h2 class=\"entry-title\">(.*?)</h2>'si" ,$html, $matches); 

foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$val)
    echo $val."<br/>";
```

Comment: @MahsumAkbas welcome.If problem solved you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your headlines are build in 3 lines. You must set the "m"-option. Maybe it helps.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

But for parsing a HTML-DOM string you should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) with getElementByTagName

Comment: actually using an XPath would fit even better than getElementsByTagName , he don't want h2 tags, he want h2 tags that also have the `class="entry-title"` attribute. but yeah

Comment: He could also check the class later ;) but your right. XPath is much easier